# Getting Value from Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

```
        data =     (
            {
        date = "2016-01-20";
        "end_time" = "11:10:00";
        "function_code" = RCV;
        "operator_id" = JOHN;
        "start_time" = "11:00:00";
        "total_time" = 10;
        "total_units" = 19;
        },
            {
        date = "2016-01-20";
        "end_time" = "12:25:00";
        "function_code" = PIK;
        "operator_id" = JOHN;
        "start_time" = "12:15:00";
        "total_time" = 10;
        "total_units" = 26;
        }
     )
```

this array containing 2 dictionary ,i have to get the endtime from the first dictionary and starttime from the second dictionary and i want to calculate the break time from this value.i know how to get the value dictionary . data[0][@"end_time"] and data[1][@"start_time"] this is sufficient if array contains two elements .but if array has more than 5 means,i want to iterate the array .i will update my code what i did ... 
my array name is arrData

```
                   for (int i 0; i<arrData.count; i++) {

                    dictData =arrData[i];


                 NSString *startTime =[dictData objectForKey:@"start_time"];

                 NSString *totalTime = [dictData objectForKey:@"total_time"];
                 NSNumber *numTotalUnits =[dictData objectForKey:@"total_units"];
                 NSString *functionCode = [dictData objectForKey:@"function_code"];
                 NSString *endTime = [dictData objectForKey:@"end_time"];
                    NSLog(@"%@",endTime);



                    [array1 addObject:endTime];


                    if (arrData[i+1] > arrData.count) {


                        dictData = arrData[i+1];
                        NSLog(@"%@",dictData);

                        NSString *strStartTime = [dictData objectForKey:@"start_time"];
                        NSLog(@"%@",strStartTime);

                        [array1 addObject:strStartTime];


                        NSLog(@"%@",array1);


                    }

             }
```

i tried this coding but i got error like index 2 beyond bounds[0..1]

Comment: `data[0][@"end_time"]` and `data[1][@"start_time"]`?

Comment: If you don't know how to get an element of an array or a dictionary, you can't program in Objective-C at all. I suggest you stop and learn the language before proceeding.

Comment: thanks for replying,sorry i forgot to mention ,here i want to calculate the break time,for that only i want end time and start time.data[0][@"end_time"] and data[1][@"start_time"] this answer is ok.if array contains 2.If it is more that 5 means,so i want to iterate it and want endtime and starttime .can u please help me?thanks in advance

Comment: @matt please see my above comment.i know how to get the element from array and dictionary .while getting i got error like index 2 beyond bounds [0..1]

Comment: You should edit the question to include the actual problem you're trying to solve.  Also include whatever code you've tried.

Comment: `foreach (NSDictionary *item in data) { NSLog(@"Start time: %@ - End time: %@", item[@"start_time"], item[@"end_time"]); }`

Comment: Index 2 _is_ beyond the bounds of this array, which has only two elements. I repeat my comment; you clearly don't know enough Objective-C to do even the most basic thing. Stop and _learn_ Objective-C first. Really.

Answer (score 1):

Try `for (int i = 0; i < arrData.count - 1; i++) {`.

In your current code, you let `i` become equal to `arrData.count - 1` in the loop, which means that when you check `i + 1` you're looking past the final array element.